# How can I describe the lifetimes for a currying function that returns generic types?

Tags: generics, functional-programming, rust, lifetime, currying

I'm trying to write a function that curries a function of two variables into a function-valued function of one variable.

When the types involved are all simple, there's no problem:

```
fn curry1(f: fn(i32, i32) -> i32) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> i32>> {
    Box::new(move |x| Box::new(move |y| f(x, y)))
}
```

Once I try to make any of the parameters generic I run into lifetime issues that I can't solve:

```
fn curry2<Z>(f: fn(i32, i32) -> Z) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> Z>> {
    Box::new(move |x| Box::new(move |y| f(x, y)))
}
```

```
the parameter type Z may not live long enough to satisfy its required lifetime bounds
```

How can I properly describe and annotate the relevant lifetimes?

Comment: Which version of the compiler are you using? The latest stable seems to provide a more useful error message for this situation. Here's [your code in the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4da5f1ad8314d557390674e0751ff436&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) (you might wish to include it in the question).

Comment: The version of the compiler active in the playground gave a much more useful error message: `consider adding an explicit lifetime bound Z: 'static'...so that the type 'closure@src/main.rs:6:32: 6:48 f:fn(i32, i32) -> Z, x:i32]' will meet its required lifetime bounds`. So I changed `fn curry2<Z>(...` to `fn curry2<Z: 'static>(...` and all is well. Looks like it's time to update my local rust installation. <a href="https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bb08515f6e5fa9ae1c6e79371940541d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015">Updated playground link</a>.

Comment: @fmg Do you want to post the details of that as an answer to the question? This seems like something a lot of people might want to know about in the future (or at least, I probably will).